# How do I convert a non gradle android project to a gradle project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Well I tried converting a simple android project to a gradle project using eclipse gradle plugin

However when converting an error was thrown which read

```
/xyz/gen already exists but is not a source folder. Convert to a source folder or rename it.
```

By default in the android project, that I am trying to convert, there's a gen folder where various files like R.java are generated.

Now what exactly am I doing wrong or missing?

Comment: gen is generated automaticaly by eclipse when compiling your project so you can delete gen and retry, no?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to convert an Eclipse project to Gradle is to import it in Android Studio 0.4.3. Direct Eclipse import was added in 0.4.0, and some important bug fixes in 0.4.3 make it the version to get at the moment.